# Microsoft edge being used in a web form 2010 app that uses javascript

Tags: visual-studio-2010, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

In a vb.net 2010 web forms application, I have found that Internet Explorer 11 does not work any longer due to the obsolete statement of

"var firstVisibleElement = Array.from(document.querySelector("#rso").children) .find(positiveClientHeight)". The Array.from no longer works.

I ran the same application in Microsoft Edge and I found that the application runs correctly.

Thus since Internet Explorer 11 does not work due to deprecated and/or obsolete JavaScript statements, are there deprecated and/or obsolete features in Microsoft Edge?

If so, can you tell me and/or point me to link(s) url(s) that will tell me what the deprecated/obsolete javascript objects are?

If there is nothing deprecated/obsolete, would you let me know that also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that EDGE only runs the most modern standard of the web.

> Microsoft Edge doesn't support ActiveX controls, Browser Helper
>   Objects, VBScript, or other legacy technology.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/deploy/emie-to-improve-compatibility

But yes, Microsoft edge DOES have legacy support, but not out of the box.

> If you have websites or
>   web apps that still use this technology and need IE11, you can add
>   them to the Enterprise Mode site list, using the Enterprise Mode Site
>   List Manager.

[image]

> Compatibility and security. Microsoft Edge lets you continue to use
>   IE11 for sites that are on your corporate intranet or that are
>   included on your Enterprise Mode Site List. You must use IE11 to run
>   older, less secure technology, such as ActiveX controls.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/deploy/enterprise-guidance-using-microsoft-edge-and-ie11